# WPF Binding к элементам, находящимся в ресурсах

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Всем доброго времени суток!

Имеется следующий код:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <col:ArrayList x:Key="dataGridDef">
            <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List1}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      Tag="{Binding Path=GridNames[0]}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Grid1Name1" Binding="{Binding Path=Name1}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <DataGrid Name="DG2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List2}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      Tag="{Binding Path=GridNames[1]}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Grid2Name1" Binding="{Binding Path=Name1}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </col:ArrayList>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="lb" ItemsSource="{StaticResource dataGridDef}" DisplayMemberPath="Tag"
                 SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedGrid}"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=lb, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        <TextBlock Height="100" Text="{Binding Path=Str.Header}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedGrid.Tag}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new Content();
        }
    }

    public class Content
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Asd> List1 { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Asd> List2 { get; set; }
        public DataGrid SelectedGrid { get; set; }

        private string[] _gridName;
        public string[] GridNames { get { return _gridName; } }

        public Content()
        {
            List1 = new ObservableCollection<Asd>();
            List2 = new ObservableCollection<Asd>();
            List1.Add(new Asd { Name1 = "1" });
            List1.Add(new Asd { Name1 = "2" });
            List2.Add(new Asd { Name1 = "a" });
            List2.Add(new Asd { Name1 = "b" });
            _gridName = new string[] { "G1", "G2" };
        }
    }
    public class Asd: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name1;
        public string Name1
        {
            get { return _name1; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _name1) return;
                _name1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name1));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        internal void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Задача состоит в следующем:

Имеется `ListBox` в котором выбирается `DataGrid`, отображаемое имя привязано к свойству `DataGrid` `Tag`, выбранный `DataGrid` отображается ниже, с которым дальше и происходит работа.
Имена `DataGrid`, а точнее его свойство `Tag` привязаны к массиву из класса `Content`.
Но! В `ListBox` не отображаются имена, до тех пор пока в нем ничего не выбрано, как только элемент выбран, отображается только его имя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, как только выбирается второй элемент, отображается имя второго элемента, имя первого отображаться перестает.

Как сделать так, что бы имена элементов в `ListBox` отображались всегда?

Comment: Не уверен что понимаю что вы хотите сделать

Comment: Напишите ответом здесь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        <!--Ссылки-->
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="525" x:Name="MyWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <col:ArrayList x:Key="dataGridDef">
            <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List1}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      Tag="{Binding Path=DataContext.GridNames[0], Source={x:Reference MyWindow}}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Grid1Name1" Binding="{Binding Path=Name1}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <DataGrid Name="DG2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List2}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      Tag="{Binding Path=DataContext.GridNames[1], Source={x:Reference MyWindow}}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Grid2Name1" Binding="{Binding Path=Name1}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </col:ArrayList>
    </Window.Resources>
```

1. Присваиваем окну имя: `x:Name="MyWindow"`
2. Задаем `Source` для `Tag`: `Source={x:Reference MyWindow}`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48679600/wpf-binding-to-elements-in-resources